# Is it just my bandwidth or is chat.stackexchange really extremely slow right now?

Tags: support, chat

All the rooms in chat.stackexchange are taking forever to load. Is there an update going on in the servers or something? At first, I had thought it was my slow Internet connection (average: 250 kbit/s; 500 kbit/s means that I am at my high), but other sites are loading quite fast, and I never had encountered chat.stackexchange being this slow before.

**Note: I am using Chrome on Windows and am browsing from [South Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asia) ([Kathmandu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathmandu), Nepal)**.

**I also tried from the [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) browser on Windows. The problem's there as well.**

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of an issue on my end (beyond the usual slowness caused by my limited bandwidth). Can you give us more info e.g. browser, OS, etc?

Comment: I am on chrome on windows.

Comment: all response times in the network tab of the Dev Console are around 100ms, so no repro for me. I'm in Western Europe in case that matters.

Comment: @rene Ah, might also be a regional issue because I am from South-Asia. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I am from India and I am not facing any problem in chat

Comment: @SagarV Strange.. I am from Nepal though...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that neither your network environment nor Stack Exchange server is faulty, but **a node in your trace route is working badly**.

This is so far the only possible reason when

- You have a bad connection to one (or a few sites)
- You have a good connection to (all) other sites
- Other people have a good connection to that site

Because a network connection may go through many nodes (usually 10~30), any one of them working badly may result in your slow connection. You can use `tracert` (Windows) or `tracepath` (Unix & Linux) to check whether there's a bad node in your connection to SE.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `tracert` There were 12 extra hops for chat.stackexchange comparing it to codegolf.stackexchange.com....  Maybe this is a problem??

Comment: @officialaimm Yes it *is* a problem. However there's nothing you can to except to file a complaint to your ISP.